# Converting Data minutes to hourly data in golang

Tags: go

I have a table in the database, it records data in minutes, how to sum it in hours and average the related columns?

I have tried to create the function, but when run there is duplicate data. Is my code wrong or the logic? I didn't create it based on raw SQL because I'm afraid it will cause expensive server prices.

I want the data to be summed sequentially until it produces hourly data, then a new row is created and the data in the cod and ph columns are averaged.

### here the code example:

```
func (server *Server) DataPerHour(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var PH, COD float64
    var countEntry float64

    sparingData := models.SparingReport{}
    sparingHourData := models.SparingReportHour{}

    countsparingdatalast, _ := sparingData.CountLastSparingReportHourByID(server.DB, 2)

    if *countsparingdatalast > 0 {
        sparingDataPerHour, _ := sparingData.FindAllSparingReport(server.DB)

        if len(*sparingDataPerHour) > 0 {
            startHour := (*sparingDataPerHour)[0].RecordedAt.Hour()

            for _, dataReceived := range *sparingDataPerHour {
                nowHour := dataReceived.RecordedAt.Hour()

                if startHour == nowHour {
                    if dataReceived.PH > 0 {
                        PH += dataReceived.PH
                    }
                    if dataReceived.COD > 0 {
                        COD += dataReceived.COD
                    }

                    countEntry++
                } else if startHour != nowHour {
                    sparingHourData.Prepare()

                    sparingHourData.ID = dataReceived.ID
                    sparingHourData.RecordedAt = dataReceived.RecordedAt
                    if countEntry > 0 {
                        sparingHourData.PH = PH / countEntry
                        sparingHourData.COD = COD / countEntry
                    }

                    sparingHourData.Prepare()
                    sparingHourData.IsProcess = true
                    _, _ = sparingHourData.SaveSparingReportHour(server.DB)

                    PH = 0
                    COD = 0
                    countEntry = 0

                    startHour = nowHour
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Here's the output

[image]

### Expected Output

| ID | RecordedAt | PH | COD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-11-17 19:00:00+00 | 7.1 | 25.5 |
| 2 | 2023-11-17 20:00:00+00 | 7.8 | 24.7 |

Comment: Please try to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); I realise this can be difficult when a database is involved, but in this case the source of the data is not relevant so you can [use something like this](https://go.dev/play/p/fa6TYjIryeH) (I've noted a couple of potential issues in the example). Note that doing the aggregation using SQL may well be less expensive than retrieving all of the data.